# How do I set up a secondary DNS server properly?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I have two windows 2003 web servers, one is the primary DNS, the other is the second DNS. If I add a new website I put a new primary zone record in the primary DNS then put a secondary zone record in the secondary DNS which then grabs the details from the primary DNS.

I've been told it's possible to set up both servers so that when a primary zone is entered into the primary DNS it automatically is added to the secondary DNS.

If this is so then how?

Ok, probably a big ask but if someone can point me to a site that gives details how to do this then it will be greatly appreciated. I have tried Googling but I must be asking the wrong question as I never find an answer.

Both servers are in the same server farm but link via the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows' DNS server can use AD-integrated DNS zones in addition to standard primary/secondary zones. When a zone is AD-integrated, it stores the zone data in AD and automatically replicates the data to other DNS servers using the underlying AD replication mechanisms. It's typically used on Domain Controllers. It doesn't sound like you are using an AD environment in this case, so this isn't much use to you.

See TechNet for more: [Active Directory-Integrated DNS Zones](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731204(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: A lot of times, people doing web hosting have the servers in remote data centers they don't own, and don't connect them to an AD domain.

Comment: That's correct, I'm not using an AD domain.

Comment: Unfortunately you're stuck doing it the way you are currently doing it then.

Comment: Ok, then I will just have to spend some time getting it all right then make sure it's updated when new sites are added. Thanks for your help folks